# Using JPA Entity Graph in DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitygraph

I have defined the JPA Entity Graph on my Entity class, and it looks like follows.

**UserTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "user-entity-graph-with-photos", 
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "photos"),
        })
public class UserTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<PhotoTable> photos = new HashSet<>();
```

The requirement is that sometimes I want to fetch the users along with the photos, and in some other cases I only want the users to be loaded from the database, but not the photos.

Now, I have created a DAO class for the User - **UserDAO.java**. In there, I have two methods, each for one case.

```
public Optional<UserTable> findByEmail(String email) {
    final TypedQuery<UserTable> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT e FROM UserTable e WHERE e.email = :email", UserTable.class);

    return Optional.ofNullable(query.setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult());
}

public Optional<UserTable> findByEmailWithPhotos(String email) {
    final TypedQuery<UserTable> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT e FROM UserTable e WHERE e.email = :email", UserTable.class);

    return Optional.ofNullable(query
            .setParameter("email", email)
            .setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", entityManager.getEntityGraph("user-entity-graph-with-photos"))
            .getSingleResult());
}
```

I am a bit worried about the API in the DAO layer, since it now contains 2 methods like **findByEmail** and **findByEmailWithPhotos** which also loads the photos eagerly. Is this the correct approach? Should we really use one DAO method for each defined entity graph? Would some kind of a builder pattern be more effective here? Any advice is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

To explain further what I feel is bad about this design is the following. Let's suppose we have 3 entity graphs on the user

1. `user-graph-with-photos`
2. `user-graph-with-messages`
3. `user-graph-with-followers`

Then in the DAO would need to have the following methods:

1. findUsers
2. findUsersWithPhotos
3. findUsersWithMessages
4. findUsersWithFollowers
5. findUsersWithPhotosAndMessages
6. findUsersWithPhotosAndFollowers
7. findUsersWithMessagesAndFollowers
8. findUsersWithPhotosAndMessagesAndFollowers

Comment: How would your proposed builder pattern work?  How would it improve on your current solution?  And what about your current solution is it that you feel _needs_  improvement?

Comment: @KevinAnderson
I feel that those are the same queries, only decorated with another "filter", so I think having two separated method that basically do the same, just the other one has some upgrade is not a good design. A builder could possibly be like Set<UserTable> users = DAO.queryBuilder().findUsers().withPhotos().query();

Comment: @KevinAnderson Please see my update

Comment: I'd suggest that instead of `findByEmail` and `findByEmailWithPhotos`, you probably should go initially with `findByEmail` and `findByEmailWithAllDetails`.  Add specific methods that eager-fetch particular combinations of attributes when (and only _if_) it makes sense,   but don't feel that you automatically _have to_ anticipate and cater to eager loading any-and-every possible combination of collection attributes from the get-go